# Открытие файла в той же директории где файл.go

Tags: файлы, golang

Есть основной пакет:

```
package main

import "testXML/dd"

func main() {

    dd.SSS()

}
```

Он подключается к пакету

```
ddfunc SSS() {

    bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("dd/ff.conf")
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("--->", err)
    }
   str := string(bs)
    fmt.Println("::::::::::::::", str)
}
```

Но можно ли сделать, что бы файл читался без префикса папки, т.е. просто "ff.conf" ?

Comment: Опишите подробнее что где у вас находится и как вы программу запускаете.

Comment: Точка входа в приложение main. Он обращается к вложенному к нему пакету и использует функцию из данного пакета. Так же в данном пакете (dd), лежит файл ff.conf. Мне необходимо открыть ff.conf с локальной директории. Без указания полного пути для функции ReadFile. Запускаю командой: go run testXML/main.go;

Comment: А контекст использования какой? Если это временная программа для разовой задачи - то какая разника как запускается. Если это предполагается потом распространять, то этот файл в компилируемый бинарник по-умолчанию всё равно не входит. Посмотрите на https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata - чтобы включать файл внутри конечной программы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ioutil.ReadFile(filename)** использует абсолютный путь. Отсюда, запуск программы даст успешное открытие и чтение файла в локальной директории при условии наличия файла с таким именем.

Ошибки могут вылезать, если использовать разные IDE типа *IntelliJ IDEA* которая при запуске компилирует временный исполняемый файл в `/tmp/рандомныйхашпроекта`.